# When using Objects as maps, its keys are always converted to strings. Why?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, ecmascript-6

The following code:

```
let user1={name: "Sam"};
let user2={name:"Tyler"};
let totalReplies={};
totalReplies[user1]=5;
totalReplies[user2]=42;
console.log(totalReplies[user1]);
console.log(totalReplies[user2]);
```

Generates the output:

```
42
42
```

I expected the output to be:

```
5
42
```

Reading up, I got that '*When using Objects as maps, its keys are always converted to strings*'. I'm not sure if I understand what this means or why object keys are converted to strings. 
Either way, understanding why the output was 42 42 should help enforce this concept.

Comment: *"Why?"* Because that's how the language was defined. *"understanding why the output was 42 42 should help enforce this concept"* Because the default string representation of any object is `[object Object]`. In other words, `user1` and `user2` produce the value when converted to strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript objects only support Strings and Symbols as keys.

In situations like this, JS coerces the object to a string value (which will be something like `[object Object]`).

So basically your code would amount to this:

```
let user1={name: "Sam"};
let user2={name:"Tyler"};
let totalReplies={};
totalReplies['[object Object]']=5;
totalReplies['[object Object]']=42;
console.log(totalReplies['[object Object]']);
console.log(totalReplies['[object Object]']);
```

You can learn more about coercion here:
http://webreflection.blogspot.ch/2010/10/javascript-coercion-demystified.html

**Solution**

If you need to use objects as keys in ES6+, you can use [`Maps`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead of objects as data storage:

```
let user1={name: "Sam"};
let user2={name:"Tyler"};
let totalReplies = new Map();
totalReplies.set(user1, 5);
totalReplies.set(user2, 42);
console.log(totalReplies.get(user1));
console.log(totalReplies.get(user2));
```

Comment: `only support Strings` is slightly too broad, ES6 Symbols can also be keys.

Answer (score 2):

According with [ECMAscript standard](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer), object property names can be either an **identifier name** (i.e. identifiers + reserved words), a **string literal**, or a **numeric literal**.

In your case `user1` and `user2` are objects, and converted into string they return both `"[object Object]"` this explain your output.

If you want to you use an object (or any primitive value) as map key, you can use the native [**Map object**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) included in *ES6 standard*.

Answer (score 0):

`totalReplies[user1]=5` means `totalReplies[{name: "Sam"}]=5` and it makes no sense. The key is always a string, not an object.

You want `totalReplies[user1.name]=5;`

Comment: I'm not sure why you say it "makes no sense"; using objects as keys for maps is perfectly sensible, it's just not something that JS supports with raw Objects.

Comment: Because `{name: "Sam"}` cannot be the valid key of an object. You can't set `myObject = { {name: "Sam"} : 5 }`, this is perfectly invalid, therefore you can't access `myObject[{name: "Sam"}]`.

Comment: If you were using the object literal syntax as the basis for your statement that it "makes no sense" you should add that to the answer.

And to be nitpicky, with ES6 you *can* write `myObject = { [{name: "Sam"}]: 5}`.  It's equivalent to `myObject = {}; myObject[{name: "Sam"}] = 5;` (and thus doesn't work as intended), but it is legal syntax.

Comment: We're talking quantum physics javascript here :) Admit that it makes no sense _in real life_.

Comment: Using objects as keys to maps is something that makes plenty of sense *in real life*, as evidenced by the fact that ES6 `Map` supports it.  (And all the other languages in the world that support it)  That's why I think your answer that simply says it "makes no sense" is unhelpful and why I downvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

And they are actually:

```
var ob = {};
console.log(ob.toString())// prints "[object Object]"
```

What is does is that the method `toString` of each object is execute and the result is the same [object Object] and since you are adding the same key twice,  the index assigned gets overriden by the new value.